# Visually intuitive proof that set of invertible operators is open

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $B(H)$ be the set of all bounded operators of $H$, equipped with the operator norm. It is well-known that the set of all invertible bounded operators forms an open subset of $B(H)$. The proof (which also applies to Banach algebras in general) seems to rely on mostly symbolic manipulation, in which given an operator $S + T$, with $S$ invertible and $T$ small, we consider the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ( S^{-1}T)^n$.

I would like to know if there is a intuitive (perhaps geometric) proof of why bounded operators which are close to an invertible bounded operator must also be invertible. My line of thought is something of the following: If $S$ is invertible and $T$ is close to $S$, then the behaviour of $T$ "can't differ too much" from that of $S$, and therefore must be invertible.

Comment: I doubt it. Of course it can't be as simple as your last sentence, or you could show that _every_ set was open...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Why can't it be as simple as my last sentence? What's stopping us from having a neat, visual proof?

Comment: I didn't say there is no simple clean visual proof. All I said was that " If S is invertible and T is close to S, then the behaviour of T "can't differ too much" from that of S, " cannot be a valid proof. Because if it's a valid proof it proves that _every_ set  is open!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am not claiming that it is a valid proof. That sentence is supposed to describe what I guess the (very vague) idea of an intuitive proof for that statement would resemble. Of course, I welcome any proof which I find visually intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that a proof you'd consider intuitive exists.

One can give a proof that $T$ is injective that you might consider simple and intuitive (in the finite-dimensional case injective implies invertible, but not in infinite dimensions):

Let $$\delta=\inf_{||x||=1}||Sx||.$$Since $S^{-1}$ is bounded it follows that $\delta>0$. And

> > **Simple Fact:** If $||S-T||<\delta$ then $T$ is injective.

Proof: If $||x||=1$ then $$||Tx||=||Sx+(Tx-Sx)||\ge||Sx||-||(S-T)x||\ge\delta-||S-T||>0.$$

Comment: $\delta$ is the radius of the largest ball you can fit into the image of the unit ball under $S$. Maybe this helps visualizing what's happening, even if strictly speaking it is limited to finite dimensions. The generalization to infinite dimensions is: $S$ is invertible if and only if $\min\{\delta(S),\delta(S^*)\} > 0$.

Comment: I didn't know that about $\min(\delta(S),\delta(S^*)$, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The picture I see is the following: Given two points $x, y \in H$, there exist balls of the same radius centered at $x$ and $y$ whose images under $S$ are disjoint and therefore a positive distance apart. Therefore, if you perturb $S$ by a map $T$ with sufficiently small operator norm, then $(S+T)x$ and $(S+T)y$ remain in small disjoint balls centered at $Sx$ and $Sy$ respectively. In particular, $(S+T)x \ne (S+T)y$.

If $S^{-1}$ is bounded, then the sufficiently small bound on $\|T\|$ is independent of $x$ and $y$. In other words, if $\|T\|$ is sufficiently small, then $S+T$ is injective.